# Unify array structure

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays

I need your help,
I have an array that contains for each month (12 months) the number of executed tasks like this :

```
[      
  ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 4, 1],     
  ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 3, 2],
  ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 3, 3],
  ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 3, 4],
  ["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 1, 1]
]
```

now i need to have an array like this :

```
[
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 4, 1],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 2],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 3],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 4],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 5],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 6],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 7],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 8],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 9],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 10],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 11],
["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 0, 12],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 7, 1],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 2],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 3],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 4],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 5],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 6],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 7],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 8],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 9],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 10],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 11],
["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 0, 12]
```

]

how to proceed please i am confused.

Comment: We are also confused about the provided output.

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL or Javascript?

Comment: i have a query form data base tha giving me number of rows with COUNT function, each array contin the number of COUNT for each user by month, i need to give zero value if the user have no rows in any month

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You'll also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an object that uses the names as keys and a sub-object to store arrays for existing months for that name using month numbers as keys

Then use a loop from 1-12 and see if month exists for that name and fill in missing item if not

```js
function fillMonthHoles(data) {
  var groupByName = {}
  data.forEach(function(arr) {
    var baseArr = arr.slice(0, 2), nameKey = baseArr.join('|');
    this[nameKey] = this[nameKey] || {baseArr : baseArr};   
    this[nameKey][arr[3]] = arr;
  }, groupByName);

  return Object.keys(groupByName).reduce(function(a, key) {
    var baseArr = groupByName[key].baseArr
    for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
      var arr = groupByName[key][i];
      if (!arr) {
        arr = baseArr.slice().concat([0, i]);
      }
      a.push(arr)
    }
    return a
  }, []);

}

var res = fillMonthHoles(data);
// loop over results and log each subarray for demo only
res.forEach(a => console.log(JSON.stringify(a)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<script>
  var data = [
    ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 4, 1],
    ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 3, 2],
    ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 3, 3],
    ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 3, 4],
    ["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 1, 1]
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: In all honesty this is probably simpler to do server side

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly.

```js
var  a = [      
  ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 4, 1],     
  ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 3, 2],
  ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 3, 3],
  ["Ilhem", "Ben Salah", 3, 4],
  ["Sghaier", "Mahmoud", 1, 1],
  ["Sghaier", "Mohammad", 15, 2],
];

var result = [];
while(a.length>0)
{
    var item = a[0], firstname = item[0], lastname = item[1];
    var matchedarr = a.filter(function(item){
            return (item[0] == firstname && item[1] == lastname);
        });
    for(var j=1;j<=12;j++)
    {
        var arr = matchedarr.filter(function(item){
            return item[3]==j;
        });
        arr = arr[0] || [item[0],item[1],0,j];
        result.push(arr);
    }
    a = a.filter(function(item){
        return item[0]!==firstname || item[1]!==lastname;
    });
}

console.log(result);
```